# Minimum allowed number of particles

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in amcl the Minimum allowed number of particles means what?

Who can give some detail explain ?

I can not know what is particles?

```
"min_particles", "int", 0, "Minimum allowed number of particles.
"max_particles", "int", 0, "Mamimum allowed number of particles.
"kld_err", "double", 0, "Maximum error between the true distribution and the estimated distribution."
"kld_z", "double", 0, "Upper standard normal quantile for (1 - p), where p is the probability that the error on the estimated distrubition will be less than kld_err."
"update_min_d", "double", 0, "Translational movement required before performing a filter update."
"update_min_a", "double", 0, "Rotational movement required before performing a filter update."
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236388/minimum-allowed-number-of-particles/) by [ligang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26953/ligang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ligang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26953/ligang/) on 2016-06-07**:
the particles is a point in a map?
or a point through the radar in one second scan?

or other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try and look up a Particle filter on google, in order to understand the parameters you need some background knowledge of the filter.
In short each particle is a simulated potential position of the robot. Each position is then scored with respect to the current laserscan and map.

The minimum number of particles is the minimum number of particles you want in your filter to maintain an accurate belief of the robots position.

---

Originally posted by [FOXTER](https://answers.ros.org/users/26976/foxter/) with karma: 153 on 2016-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1